# Font size issue with iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile, mobile-safari

Im currently working on a mobile version of a website, everything is great, works fine on an iPhone, Blackberry and Android.

I have one slight problem, not a big deal but still a little annoying. I have:

`<h1>` tags set to 18px and bold
`<h2>` tags set to 12px and bold
`<p>` tags set to 12px and normal

Now everything looks great on the iPhone when viewing in portrait, but when the device is rotated to landscape the `<h1>` titles go smaller (hard to tell but possibly smaller than the `<h2>` tags?!

Here is my css:

```
h1 {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font-size:18px;
 line-height:22px;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-top:0px;
}

h2 {
 font-size:12px;
 color:#333333;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-bottom:-5px;
}

p {
 color:#333333;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:18px;
 font-weight:normal;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserve HTML font-size when iPhone orientation changes from portrait to landscape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710764/preserve-html-font-size-when-iphone-orientation-changes-from-portrait-to-landsca)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this in your CSS:

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Prevent font scaling in landscape */
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Cheers, shall mark answer as correct soon as i can!

Comment: After hours of playing you saved my life !
Thanks @Neurofluxation.

Comment: Believe me, when I found out about it - My jaw dropped, I started sweating and my heart skipped a beat... But really all I did was shout "F*CK YEAH"

Comment: But why does 'span' tag resize text on rotation and 'a' tag not?!

Comment: Thanks Dude ! Css is amazing and so are you !!

Answer (score 17):

A better solution can be using 100% instead of none, as stated by user612626 in an older thread:
[Font size rendering inconsistencies on an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545542/font-size-render-in-iphone)

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

this way desktop webkit browsers can adjust size and zoom proportionally too.
I think this is a better approach than filtering by screen size.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 14):

As stated in Neurofluxation's answer you can use the css rule -webkit-text-size-adjust but beware that this can prevent users from adjusting the font size on desktop Webkit as well (see [this article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/beware_of_-webkit-text-size-adjustnone/) for more details).

In light of this it's likely worth checking via CSS3 media queries (or user agent) to be safe.

E.g.,

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; 
    }
}
```