# Text shrinks on mobile website on Iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, mobile

I have a website (maxbraun.us). I've noticed that, on the home page of the mobile version, sometimes when the page loads (and always when the page is reloaded) the font shrinks a great deal and makes everything look bad. But nothing else changes. I am wondering if anyone knows why this happens and how I can fix it. I am on an Iphone 5 by the way.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If your pages are set up to HTML5 you could use the line: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> on each page. Otherwise investigate Media Queries that can force a font size depending on the device width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to resize the text:

```
<p style="font-size: 500%">Coding Like a Pro!</p>
```

Hope this helped

Comment: yes, I know how to set the size of text. It usualy is the right size but it changes when I reload the page, but only on my Iphone.

Comment: This question has already been answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466434/font-size-issue-with-iphone?rq=1