# My site Font-Size does not display correctly on ios Safari

Tags: html, css

the site is https://mizore.site

1. on safari, the font-size is too big
   [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8GIq.png)
2. on other [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWvvU.png)

It's only happend on ios safari, It display correctly on ipad safari, ios's other browsers.

I have no Mac, so I use inspect.dev to debug it, found the p font-size is 24px

[inspect.dev debug img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxdvf.png)

Hope anyone can help me!

Comment: Hope this will help you. I found this also in Stack overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466445/19100039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this in the CSS

```
html {
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Prevent font scaling in landscape */
```

}