# How to rescale text size?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, text, resize

I've created a modal on my app which the content is designed to fit onto the Iphone 6. However when I open the modal on the Iphone 5s, the content text is too big. Is there a way in the CSS to make the app resize the text based on the phone its on?

**Currently I have in the CSS**:

```
.firstParagraph {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 80px;
  font-size: 12;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545542/font-size-render-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
font-size: 20vw;
```

To make the text 20% av the screen width no matter the device. (Modern device that is).