# different font-sizes on mobile web (iPhone) for font set at 14px for font-size

Tags: ios, css, font-size, mobile-website

I have a web property and when viewing in an iphone, the fonts are all different even though they are set at 14px ....

```
font-size: 14px;
```

Here's a a screenshot from my iPhone 6 Plus:

[image]

Looking in chrome developer set for mobile, it is rendering fine but not on iPhone.

What is going on (link if answered before) and how do I fix this?

Comment: Post your code, not just a screenshot. We need a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: the site is: http://www.aocwinebar.com/dinner.html so might be faster (and more complete to look at that). I want it to be consistent at a minimum.

Comment: In Firefox (Mac), all text has the same size

Comment: @timpone we shouldn't have to go to a 3rd party site to see the issue. Plus, that does nothing to help the SO community 2 years from now when someone searches for your issue, lands on your post, and your site has changed and doesn't show the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)?

Comment: @MatheusAvellar - not yet, not a front-end dev so looking into it.

Comment: I tried using the `-webkit-text-size-adjust` technique here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4966556/152825 but doesn't seem to work