# how to use CSS set a div single-line or multi-line style?

Tags: html, css

If a div is single-line, i want its height is 80px.

Else if it is multi-line, i want its padding-top-bottom is 20px.

I have tried to do this:

```
div {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

But,it works not well in the following single-line cases in the **iPhone browser**：

```
<div>中文abc</div>
<div>123abc</div>
```

If the innerHTML contains Chinese,the div's height will exceed 80px.

So,is there any other way?

Comment: `If the innerHTML contains Chinese,the div's height will exceed 80px.` You are wrong or not sufficiently describing your problem.  `<div>中文abc</div>` with the css you gave has the exact height of 80px in all (reasonable) browsers. http://plnkr.co/edit/5f7aoX2ghJkaq0t4Z5o3?p=preview

Comment: sorry,I forgot to say that this would happen in the iPhone browser

Comment: the height of div actually depends on font size as long as you're not forcing the height and setting overflow-hidden or something

Comment: There is also `max-height`

Comment: the point is why the div's height is different when the FontSize is same

Comment: I believe it's because the font-size is *actually* not the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545542/font-size-rendering-inconsistencies-on-an-iphone might help you out.